# Is there a way to have sub-transactions in Gatling?

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

Requested page returns multiple results, response time of the requested page accordingly varies depending on the number of results.

With Gatling I'm having one transaction with all response times in it, in addition I'd like to have sub-transactions depending on the range of results for example:

```
BuildTable (10Txs)
BuildTable_0_10 (2Txs)
BuildTable_10_100 (6Txs)
BuildTable_100_all (2Txs)
```

The main goal to have this break-down visible in report, Any idea how can I reach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to have "transactions" in Gatling is to use "groups". But they wrap the delimited sequence of requests, so its name is computed before entering the sequence, hence in your case, before knowing the number of results.

So the only way is to know beforehand the number of expected results, e.g. like having this information in a feeder along some search keywords, and either switch to different branches, or compute the group name dynamically with a function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, computing group names dynamically solves one part of the problem. Returned results are volatile, no way to know those values beforehand. It would be cool to have a way for logging/reporting virtual requests, without actually sending requests.

Comment: I really don't see a way with the current design. The sole solution is to make your results non volatile, which also looks to me like a better test design (reproducible).